# How to filter a specific record in SQL Server within in the date range without removing other records?

Tags: sql, t-sql, ssms-2017

I am using SSMS 2017.

Below is a source table,

[image: Source Table]

from the above table I want to filter only 'i' records

[image: Records that needs to be removed]

in which the date difference is >=6 months by satisfying the following condition (date2 <= dateadd(MONTH, +6, date1 - datepart(MONTH, date1) -1)) and the result should be as following,

[image: Result table]

any help from any one will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select t.*
from t
where name <> 'i' or
      date2 <= dateadd(month, +6, date1 - datepart(month, date1) -1))
```

I'm not quite sure what your condition is supposed to be doing, but this is what is in your question.

Based on the logic in the text:

```
select t.*
from t
where name <> 'i' or
      date2 <= dateadd(month, +6, date1)
```